# BigQuery Standard SQL: Delete Duplicates from Table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using below query to delete duplicates records from bigquery using standard sql. but it is throwing error

```
with cte as (
select * ,row_number()over (partition by CallRailCallId order by CallRailCallId) as rn
from `encoremarketingtest.EncoreMarketingTest.CallRailCall2` )

delete
 from cte
where rn>1
```

> ```
> Query Failed
> Error: Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT but got keyword DELETE at [5:5]
> ```

Could anyone help me on the correct approach in BigQuery?

Comment: try delete from cte where rn>1;

Comment: tried but same error

Answer (score 10):

> Option #1

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.dataset.your_table` AS
SELECT * EXCEPT(rn)
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CallRailCallId ORDER BY CallRailCallId) rn
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
) 
WHERE rn = 1
```

> Option #2

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.dataset.your_table` AS
SELECT row.*
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY CallRailCallId LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] row
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table` t
  GROUP BY CallRailCallId
)
```

As you might noticed, above options using [`DDL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language)(CREATE TABLE) approach and that is where it is possible to use just one known (from your question) column - `CallRailCallId`
Also, note - `ORDER BY CallRailCallId` plays no real role there because GROUP BY and PARTITION BY are by exactly same filed. But if you change the field this will control which exactly row (out of few duplicates) to "survive" (For example `ORDER BY ts DESC` - see below option for what ts might be)

> Option #3

This option uses [`DML`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax)(DELETE FROM) but requires some extra column to be used to serve as a tie-breaker

For example you have `ts` TIMESTAMP field and you want the most recent (based on ts) row to survive

```sql
DELETE FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
WHERE STRUCT(CallRailCallId, ts) NOT IN (
  SELECT AS STRUCT CallRailCallId, MAX(ts) ts
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
  GROUP BY CallRailCallId
  )
```

Comment: @mayank - did you have chance to try?

Comment: Third option didnot work, 1st one work for me, I did not tried 2nd option