# BigQuery - DELETE statement to remove duplicates Group by Id

Tags: google-bigquery, duplicates, delete-row

I am trying to use `DELETE` to remove duplicate records from my BigQuery table.

I found multiple solutions to the above question but most of them use `CREATE`, `REPLACE` or `SELECT`.

The closest solution using `DELETE` I found was:

[BigQuery - DELETE statement to remove duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130324/bigquery-delete-statement-to-remove-duplicates)

[BigQuery Standard SQL: Delete Duplicates from Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50523927/bigquery-standard-sql-delete-duplicates-from-table)

I have a follow up questions on the below solution:

```
#standardSQL
DELETE FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.duplicates`
WHERE STRUCT(id, loadTime) NOT IN (
    SELECT AS STRUCT id, MAX(loadTime) loadTime 
    FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.duplicates` where id= '123'
    GROUP BY id)
```

This statement deletes all the records from the table which does not satisfy the `NOT IN` condition. For example, if my table looks like below:

```
Id      Loadtime
123        5
123        4
456        2
321        1
```

The query above deletes all records except for the first row. 
How can I modify the query so that it deletes only the 2nd row i.e. it only deletes group by id?

The final output should be:

```
 Id      Loadtime
 123        5
 456        2
 321        1
```

Comment: provide example of input/initial data and expected result

Comment: what the logic behind picking Loadtime 5 over 4 - do you want to leave the entry with bigger Loadtime or some other reason?

Comment: Yes. For each Id I only want the row with max(LoadTime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work as per your expectation

```
#standardSQL
DELETE FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.duplicates`
WHERE STRUCT(id, loadTime) NOT IN (
SELECT AS STRUCT id, MAX(loadTime) loadTime 
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.duplicates` 
GROUP BY id)
```

so, in your sample - it will delete ONLY second row

```
Id  Loadtime     
123 4
```

Comment: It is only keeping the 1 record which satisfies the  subquery result and deleting the rest.

Comment: the rest in same `id` group - right? isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: It was deleting rows with Id 456 and 521. I just removed the condition where id= '123' from my query and it only deleted the 2nd row and kept 1st, 3rd and 4th row. Not sure why the where clause would cause this but it works now! Thanks for your help

Comment: yes, that's exactly what my answer points to. glad you made it work :o)