# Google BiqQuery: How delete dublicate rows from table without any extra colum

Tags: google-bigquery, dml

I have table with two columns, where there are duplicates:

```
select record_id,
       session_id,
       count(record_id) as total_duplicate_records
from `project.dataset.table` 
group by 1,2
order by 3 desc
```

The output looks like:
[image]

I saw a similar question: [BigQuery Standard SQL: Delete Duplicates from Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50523927/bigquery-standard-sql-delete-duplicates-from-table)
but an answer based on some extra column to be used to serve as a tie-breaker. In my case there is no such column...

The goal is to run a scheduled query that will delete all duplicate records once a day

Comment: Hi @Gross, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SELECT DISTINCT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_distinct) to deduplicate your table.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
    `project.dataset.table` -- this will overwrite your table
AS

SELECT DISTINCT
    record_id,
    session_id
FROM
    `project.dataset.table`
```

### Create a new table

Replace the table to be replaced or created with a new name. This will create a new table. Running the query again will recreate/overwrite the new table.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
    `project.dataset.table_deduped` -- change to a new table
AS

SELECT DISTINCT
    record_id,
    session_id
FROM
    `project.dataset.table`
```

Some potential drawbacks:

- you are storing your data twice. (The duplicated and deduplicated tables)
- You have to recreate the table each time you get new data in your original table, however you can instead of recreating it, insert new data via a [merge statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement)

### Create a [VIEW](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro)

A view is a virtual table based on a query. The data is not stored in a new table. You query it the same way you query a table. Can be useful if the underlying table or tables gets updated and you always want an up to date 'view' of the data.

```sql
CREATE VIEW
    `project.dataset.table_deduped` -- change to a new table
AS

SELECT DISTINCT
    record_id,
    session_id
FROM
    `project.dataset.table`
```

### Use a cte table ([WITH clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause))

Create a temporary table that you can reference inside the same query.

```sql
WITH 
    deduped_table AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            record_id,
            session_id
        FROM
            `project.dataset.table`
)

SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    deduped_table
```

All the options have their pro's and cons. Depending on what you want to achieve, how your data is structured and how much you need to care about the amount of data your are querying/storing. If you only have the two columns it's probably not that big of a deal but worth noting your options in any case I rate.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without overwriting the table?

Comment: I've updated the answer to give a few options that you can consider.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this. It will replace the existing table with one row per unique combination of record_id and session_id

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `project.dataset.table`
AS
SELECT
  record_id, session_id
FROM
  `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

**Input Table:**

[image]

If all the rows having all fields as duplicate, you can consider below approach

```
select as value any_value(t)
from `project.dataset.table1` t
group by format('%t', t)
```

**Output:**

[image]

To use it with DDL, you can consider below approach:

```
create or replace table `project.dataset.table2` as
select * from (
 select as value any_value(t)
 from `project.dataset.table1` t
 group by format('%t', t)
);
```

**Output Table**:

[image]